# JVectorMap Drill-Down doesn't color regions when scale or values change after clicking on a country

Tags: javascript, ruby, coffeescript, jvectormap

I am using JVectorMap to display some visits data over a map. This is the code.

```js
var euroMap =  new jvm.MultiMap({
      container: $('#map'),
      regionsSelectable: true,
    regionsSelectableOne: true,
      maxLevel: 1,
      main: {
        map: 'europe_mill',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        regionStyle: {
          initial: {
            fill: 'white',
            "fill-opacity": 1,
            stroke: '#000',
            "stroke-width": 0.3,
            "stroke-opacity": 1
          },
        },
        series: {
          regions: [{
            scale: ['#FFFFFF', '#DB715C'],
            values: gon.map_data['ptps'],
            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
          }]
        },
        onRegionTipShow: function(event, label, index){
           label.html(
            '<b>'+label.html()+'</b></br>'+
            '<b>#{t 'navbar.views'}: </b>'+(gon.map_data['views'][index]==undefined ? "0" : gon.map_data['views'][index])+'</b></br>'+
            '<b>#{t 'navbar.ptps'}: </b>'+(gon.map_data['ptps'][index]==undefined ? "0" : gon.map_data['ptps'][index])+'</b></br>'+
            '<b>#{t 'navbar.payments'}: </b>'+(gon.map_data['payments'][index]==undefined ? "0" : gon.map_data['payments'][index])+'</b></br>'+
            '<b>Payed/Viewed: </b>'+(gon.map_data['v_p_ratio'][index]==undefined ? "0" : gon.map_data['v_p_ratio'][index])+'%<br/>'+
            '<b>Negotiated/Viewed: </b>'+(gon.map_data['v_n_ratio'][index]==undefined ? "0" : gon.map_data['v_n_ratio'][index])+'%<br/>'+
            '<b>Payed/Negotiated: </b>'+(gon.map_data['n_p_ratio'][index]==undefined ? "0" : gon.map_data['n_p_ratio'][index])+'%<br/>'
          );
        },
        onViewportChange: function(event, scale) {},
        onRegionOver: function(event, code) {},
        onRegionClick: function(event, code) {}
      },
      mapUrlByCode: function(code, multiMap){
        return '/assets/maps/'+code.toLowerCase()+'_'+multiMap.defaultProjection+'.js';
      }
    });
```

What happens if that I have a dropdown button which runs this code(coffeescript):

```js
$('.map_selector').click (event) ->
      event.preventDefault()
      map = $('#map .jvectormap-container').data('mapObject')
      map.series.regions[0].clear()
      
      map.series.regions[0].setValues(gon.map_data[event.currentTarget.dataset.filter])
      map.series.regions[0].setScale(['#FFFFFF', '#DB715C'])
```

And it's supposed to reset the map scale and values and color the map again based on the new data.

The base map is the map of europe, and while working in this map, everything works fine, when I change the map_selector, all the map colors change again depending on the new values, but when i click on any country to see the region's data, does not work, the regions remain the same color no matter how many times I change de map_selector.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finnally I was able to solve this by creating a new instance of the map every time the values changed, because in a Drill-Down map everytime you change the values it affects the general map, in my case Europe, but does not affect the sub-regions.

So, instead of this

```html
map.series.regions[0].setValues
```

You have to generate a new instance of the map reloading the values and the Drill-down regions will be filled correctly.